# How to get value of XML tag (which contains namespace) using PHP's simplexml_load_string?

Tags: php, xml, soap

How do I get the value of "TagOne" (i.e. foo) and TagTwo (i.e. bar) from the XML below using
**simplexml_load_string**? I'm stumped by the namespace called "ns" in the tag.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
```

```
<SOAP-ENV:Body>

    <ns:ExampleInterface_Output xmlns:ns="http://example.com/interfaces">
        <ns:TagOne>Foo</ns:TagOne>
        <ns:TagTwo>Bar</ns:TagTwo>
    </ns:ExampleInterface_Output>

</SOAP-ENV:Body>
```

Thanks very much for your kind help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this code:

```
<?php

$xml = <<<XML
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
                   xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"
                   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
        <ns:ExampleInterface_Output xmlns:ns="http://example.com/interfaces">
            <ns:TagOne>Foo</ns:TagOne>
            <ns:TagTwo>Bar</ns:TagTwo>
        </ns:ExampleInterface_Output>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
XML;

$xse = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);
$exampleInterface = $xse
    ->children('SOAP-ENV', true)
    ->children('ns', true);

foreach ($exampleInterface->children('ns', true) as $key => $value) {
    //Do your stuff
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much @m4t1t0. Very kind of you to provide the code. Works beautifully. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Well you can declare the "ns" namespace to simplexml_load_string like this:

```
$xml = simplexml_load_string($string, "SimpleXMLElement", 0, "ns", TRUE);
```

This says that "ns" is a namespace prefix (rather than a namespace URL). See the [PHP doc page for simplexml_load_string](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.simplexml-load-string.php) for more details.

Another problem is that the `Body` element has a "SOAP-ENV" prefix which is not declared anywhere in the XML, so you will get a warning about this. However, the value of `$xml` will become an object structured like this:

```
SimpleXMLElement Object (
    [ExampleInterface_Output] => SimpleXMLElement Object (
        [TagOne] => Foo
        [TagTwo] => Bar
    )
)
```

But, warning aside, this might be exactly what you need. If the warning is a problem, you can simply remove the "SOAP-ENV" prefix from the start and end tags of the `Body` element.

Comment: Thank you @Arkanon, for illustrating the structure of the xml object. Very nice of you. I'm sure it will be helpful for others in their understanding.